# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) with pointer that is assigned on retval

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind

I get this Valgrind output (that's the only error I get):

```
==20627== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20627==    at 0x804913A: main (main.c:223)
```

My `main.c` roughly looks like this:

```
//other code

char **sets;

//other code

//char** get_char_sets(FILE *source);
sets = get_char_sets(config_file); // I malloc the sets in here

//other code

int i = 0;
while(sets[i]){ // line 223
    free(sets[i]);
    i++;
}
free(sets);

//other code
```

`get_char_sets` looks like this:

```
char** get_char_sets(FILE *source){

    char **sets = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char*));

    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        sets[i] = malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
    }

    //rest of function

    return sets;
}
```

I understand that valgrind says that i'm working with an uninitialized variable, the only one I can possibly see is `sets`, but it gets `malloc()`ed in `get_char_sets()` and than assigned with the returned pointer.

How can I get rid of that valgrind error in order to correct my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit on the value of `i`, which will eventually result in out of bounds:

```
while(sets[i]){
```

Change to (something like):

```
int i = 0;
while(i <= n && sets[i]){ /* Ensure check i <= n before accessing sets */
    free(sets[i]);
    i++;
}
free(sets);
```

You could also add a `NULL` sentinel value into `sets` and the `while` as is would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> while(sets[i]) { // line 223
>     free(sets[i]);
>     i++;
> }
> ```

At some point the allocated sets will end. Then `sets[i]` will point outside the allocated memory, to something you didn't set.

Given the rest of your code, you could fix it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) /* Note < instead of <=. */
    sets[i] = malloc(1);

size[n] = NULL; /* Add terminator marker. */
```

Answer (score 3):

You `malloc` all `n+1` allocated `char*` from `sets`,

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    sets[i] = malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
}
```

so unless a `malloc` failed, they're all non-`NULL`. But then you go `free`ing until you find a `NULL`,

```
int i = 0;
while(sets[i]){ // line 223
    free(sets[i]);
    i++;
}
```

which would access past the end of the allocated (to `sets`) memory, and thus invoke undefined behaviour.